# Calculate time left from specific datetime in php

Tags: php, datetime

may I know how do I calculate time left from specific datetime in php?

Example I want user can request a new confirmation code after 30 minute if already requested.

```
$request_date = '2012-03-24 13:03:17';
$please_wait  = '30 minutes';
```

How do I calculate the time left?

Comment: Take a look at the list of PHP date/time functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php.

Comment: You need two dates to calculate the difference between them (the time left). Your question has only one date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time left for new confirmation code:

```
$request_date = '2012-03-24 13:03:17';
$please_wait  = '30 minutes';
$future_time = strtotime("+" . $please_wait, strtotime($request_date));
$time_left = $future_time - time(); //seconds left
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strtotime("+" . $please_wait, strtotime($request_date));
```

Try

```
php> $request_date = '2012-03-24 13:03:17';

php> $please_wait  = '30 minutes';

php> echo strtotime("+" . $please_wait, strtotime($request_date));
1332576197
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$thirty_minutes_in_the_future = strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($request_date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the requested timestamp and sustract with currect time stamp

Solution:

```
$future = strtotime($request_date)+1800; // 1800 is 30 minutes
echo date("i", $future-time()); //this is the remaining minutes
```

Comment: @user1286499, Oops, it was a typo. Fixed it